# Estimating probabilities based on non-deterministic models

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, ranking

### Problem

I have $N$ binary classification models $M_{i}$ that try to predict there own random variable $Y_{i}$ based on the same input data $X$. Each $M_{i}$ is non-deterministic meaning every estimate of $Y_{i}$ given the same $X$ is not the same. As a note, the estimates are probabilities.

The ultimate goal is then to rank these estimates with a quantifiable degree of confidence that they are in the correct order.

### Current approach

I iteratively estimate each $Y_{i}$ until the combination of medians across all $Y_{i}$ are statistically different using [Mood's Median Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_test) or until I hit a maximum number of iterations.

As an example, here $N=4$. The dotted lines are each estimate's distribution median. (There is a kernel density estimation just to better see the distributions.)

[[image: Distribution of <span class=]$Y_{i}$ estimates" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWpMR.png)

### Questions

1. Repeating the process described above seems to rank the estimates in a different order more often than it should. Not only that, but the p-values generated from the median test vary wildly between trials (each repeat of the process). Is this because of the median test's low power?
2. Is there a more robust way to rank estimates or collection of estimates given some input $X$? I feel like using some sort of Bayesian inference and/or beta distributions is applicable here but I don't know how something like that would work.
3. Given a distribution of probability estimates from a single $M_{i}$, which measure of central tendency makes the most sense to use?